# Could not determine artifacts for com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.9: Skipped due to earlier error

Tags: android, gradle

Just building my new app and after launching I get this error in my `build.gradle` file can anyone help?

```
Could not determine artifacts for com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.9: Skipped due to earlier error
```

I have made sure the app in settings is offline but still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

stopping vpn and invalidate cache and restart solved the problem

Comment: I have done that but still having the same error. Any other ideas, please?

Comment: try to disable offlinle mode

Answer (score 0):

Fast answer - `connect to any VPN` (in my case USA VPN worked)

Explanation:

This depends on Jitpack libraries in your project.
I recently had the same issue when got the new project from a client. The client then told me that the project was building from scratch successfully, and after some research I've found that loading of some Jitpack libraries constantly failed. At first I tried to increase gradle connection timeout, but then I suddenly found that just connecting to USA VPN worked