# can't find git repo (library)

Tags: android, gradle

```
Could not find com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.9.
Required by:
    project :app
Search in build.gradle files
```

I was trying to use the library. I had searched for 2.1, 2.0 and 1.9 none of them are working. I had searched through [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858107/could-not-determine-artifacts-for-com-github-kunzisoftandroid-switchdatetimepic#58251820) I had found similar issue but that bug didn't match with mine. Why I can't find the repo? My network connection is well. When I had sync the project I didn't get any error but I am getting error when trying to run the project. There's no other error I have seen.

```
implementation 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.9'
```

`compile` is deprecated that's why I am using `implementation`. Here's the git repo link : https://github.com/Kunzisoft/Android-SwitchDateTimePicker

Comment: Did you add the maven repository link?

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan Yes! `repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }` They are available by default in new version

Comment: maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } this part

Comment: @AbdullahZKhan :| It's not required since I have `mavenCentral()` and I have gave it a try also.. :| Although I get same error

Comment: @IstiakShovon It _is_ required as it's not part of the Maven Central repository. Searching for such a package yields no results on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.Kunzisoft%20AND%20a:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker), but does on [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/#Kunzisoft/Android-SwitchDateTimePicker).

Answer (score -1):

At first you have to add

```
maven { url "jitpack.io" }
```

in settings.gradle. I was facing the issue after adding that line also. When I had reboot my system it's working fine then. You can try to close and re-run Android Studio also. I think that might be helpful also.